# Test complex method that uses a service

Tags: services, testing

I have a method of a class that returns me the list of fields that have been created outside of core Drupal. The method is the following.

```php
/**
   * @param $contentType
   * @return array $fields
   */
  public function getContentTypeFields($contentType) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManagerInterface $entityManager */
    $entityManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
    $fields = array();

    if (!empty($contentType)) {
      $fields = array_filter(
        $entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $contentType),
        function ($fieldDefinition) {
          return $fieldDefinition instanceof FieldConfigInterface;
        }
      );
    }

    return $fields;
  }
```

It accepts a content type name and returns an array of fields that aren't the default Drupal fields.

How can I write a unit Test for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resurrecting this.  The first method would be to include the EntityFieldManager as an argument to your function or constructor, so you can send a mock object in.

The second would be to look at some of the tests in core.  Specifically core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorageTest.php where the container is mocked and dependencies set up.

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->set('entity_type.manager', $entity_type_manager->reveal());
...
\Drupal::setContainer($container);
```